# Background color of UIView defaults to black, trying to change programmatically in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to change the background color of a subview in my app, but it is always appearing black.

I've found that the only thing that works is, in the convenience initializer, typing:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

If I type that same line at the beginning of my draw function, or I try to change the variable in the class by using

```
    override backgroundColor {
        get {
            return UIColor.white }
        set {
            // do nothing }
    }
```

doesn't work. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: What's the problem with your working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing a convenience initializer, *override* the two *designated* initializers that might be used to generate a UIView, namely `init(frame:)` and `init?(coder:)`. Now all instances of that view subclass will be configured as you specify.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!!